# Why did the stand "Notorious B.I.G" change to "Notorius Chase" in the anime?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

In episode 24 *Jojo Bizarre Adventure: Golden Wind*, there is a scene where a new stand named *Notorius B.I.G* appears, but on the wall it's called "Notorius Chase." Why is there this difference? Is it just some mistake in the voice-acting or key animation ? The wiki page also states that the stand Name is officially [Notorious B.I.G](https://jojo.fandom.com/wiki/Notorious_B.I.G), not "Notorius Chase."

[image]

Comment: Most likely because of copyright laws outside of Japan. A lot of name changes are in Eyes of Heaven, too

Comment: It doesn’t make any sense actually why it says chase bc in the English version on Netflix at least has notorious B.I.G written down but he says chase so i reall don’t understand why there’s two versions of the written thing idk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't gotten to that part of JJBA yet, so this is an educated guess.

Like a number of other characters in the franchise, such as ACDC, Pet Shop, and Jean Pierre Polnareff, Notorious B.I.G. is named after [a real-life musician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Notorious_B.I.G.). In a number of cases, these character names are [modified](https://jojo.fandom.com/wiki/JoJo_Wiki:Name_Variants) in localizations presumably to avoid potential trademark issues. For instance, [Steely Dan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steely_Dan) becomes *Dan of Steel*, [Terence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terence_Trent_D%27Arby) D'Arby is *D'Arby the Younger*, Kenny G is *Billie Jean*, etc.

I can only assume that something similar happened here. I don't have access to the episode right now, but [this Reddit user](https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/b6zwto/jojo_no_kimyou_na_bouken_ougon_no_kaze_episode_24/ejoa3q0/) suggests the same thing and reports that some of the animation was changed.

Comment: Not sure if Billie Jean refers to Kenny G. It most likely refers to a song by Michael Jackson whereas Kenny G's songs are of an entirely different genre...Unless it's a nickname of Kenny G's that I'm not aware of. In which case, I would be wrong.

Comment: Many of the characters are named after bands or singers explicitly in the Japanese version, rather than songs. Billie Jean is one of such [name changes](https://twitter.com/demifiendrsa/status/596834082429931520?lang=en) Maroon mentions. Given his Stand name, it makes more sense.

Comment: @кяαzєя Ah, I see. It just confused me as someone who listens to both their songs because I see no connection between the two, aside from the fact that both are related to music. Kenny G has songs that can be used as someone's name (Baby-G or G-bop) but I guess they probably think it doesn't sound as cool as Billie Jean...

Answer (score 0):

Localization. Due to making sure Japan doesn't get copyrighted, they change the names on the subtitles to say something different.